# "ontimeupdate" not working in my JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I am trying to output the time of the video duration as it progresses using the `ontimeupdate` event handler on the video but it doesn’t work.

I added a `console.log` in the code as well to test but it doesn’t work.

This is the HTML code:

```html
<video id="poster" class="w-100 h-100 image-align" autoplay muted loop src="<?= word("URL_VIDEO") ?>" loading="lazy"></video>

<span id="poster-duration" class="ms-4 text-white">00:00</span>
```

Here is my script:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var poster = document.getElementById('poster');

  poster.ontimeupdate = function(){
    document.getElementById('poster-duration').innerText = addO(Math.floor(poster.duration/60)) + ':' + addO(Math.round(poster.duration%60));
    console.log("hello")
  };

  function addO(n){
    if( n.toString().length < 2 ){
      return '0'+n;
    }

    return n;
  }

  // ...
});
```

Comment: Why do you have an extra `()` after `window.addEventListener("load", function(){`…`})`? Use the [browser console (dev tools)](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`), read any errors.

Comment: The "()" is to call the function, there is no error in the console. I removed the "()" but it is still the same result.

Comment: What function? `window.addEventListener(`…`)` isn’t a function. That’s exactly what the console will tell you, too: _“Uncaught `TypeError`: `window.addEventListener(...)` is not a function”_.

Comment: I removed it already.

Comment: Okay, if you didn’t get an error, then clearly you’re not including the JS correctly. Show how you include the JS, [edit] this question.